Read key/value file and update the value of a specific key
Using Terraform, I'm trying to read key/value pairs from an external file, update one of the values, and use the resulting data as an input into a resource.
I can successfully read key/value pairs from the external file, but I'm having difficulty in updating the required value.
My exact scenario is that I have multiple deployments with the same S3 backend, but a different key, and I need to reference the output of one of these deployments as an input in another using the terraform_remote_state resource.
For example, if my file ./backend/myenv.tfbackend contained the following...
bucket = "mybucket"
key    = "path/to/my/key"
region = "us-east-1"

I'd like for a local variable called backend_conf_other to contain the following object, where key has been updated:
{
  bucket = "mybucket"
  key    = "path/to/another/key"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

So far I have the following. How can I amend this code so that the value of local.backend_conf_other is as described above?
variable "other_key" {
  type    = string
  default = "path/to/another/key"
}


data "local_file" "backend_conf" {
  filename = "./backend/myenv.tfbackend"
}

locals {
  backend_conf_other = {
    for key, value in data.local_file.backend_conf.content :
      key => key == "key" ? value : var.other_key
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "other_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config  = local.backend_conf_other
}


The easiest path forward here is to use the merge function to overwrite key-value pairs in your map and return a new map to be assigned to the local variable:
locals {
  backend_conf_other = merge(jsondecode(data.local_file.backend_conf.content), { "key" = "path/to/another/key" })
}

Note the following from the documentation:

If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence.

Additionally the file needs to be converted to a format which can be decoded by Terraform with a native function. This answer selects JSON arbitrarily. The file content would then need to appear like:
{
  "bucket": "mybucket",
  "key": "path/to/my/key",
  "region": "us-east-1"
}


Thanks but that failed. Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "string". I think the issue is that the file is read as a string literal, so if possible that needs to be turned into a map itself first.

@DavidGard Yes I thought the string had already been decoded in your question, but I see now that was a misread on my part; updating. Also the updated answer assumes JSON format string for your file. You currently use HCL2, but there is no function in TF to decode HCL2, and so your file needs to be converted to a supported format. I chose JSON arbitrarily.

Thank you, that appears to work and happily .tfbackend files formatted as JSON seem to work. Much applicated.

@DavidGard by the way if you need HCL2 format then you could also try declaring variables in the config and using the file as a TF variable input file. I am unsure if that would feasible in your environment though.
